# how should I `extract Sunday` from the week and then enter it in console as the last day of the week

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to extract `sunday` from the week and I want it in the console as the last day of the week only after i enter it in the prompt. If someone can please let me know and rectify how to do it.

```js
function days(){
  var daysOfWeek = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"];
  let currentDay = prompt("Enter day of week:");
  let dayNum = daysOfWeek.indexOf(currentDay);
  while (dayNum < 0) {
    currentDay = prompt("Invalid day. Enter day of week:").toLowerCase();
    dayNum = daysOfWeek.indexOf(currentDay);
  }
  
  let daysLeft = daysOfWeek.splice(dayNum+1).concat(daysOfWeek.splice(0, dayNum))
  
  
  console.log(daysLeft);
  }
  days();
```

Comment: can you give an example of what you would enter in the prompt, and what the resulting output would be - your question is vague

Comment: what I want is my week should end on saturday for any day entered in the prompt.

Comment: e.g:- If entered monday so console should display days`tuesday to saturday`

Comment: so ... exclude sunday from the array if the input isn't sunday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking you want to print in output but what I see in the code you are trying to print is how many days are remaining in the week.
that you can do with

```
function days(){
  var daysOfWeek = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"];
  let currentDay = prompt("Enter day of week:");
  let dayNum = daysOfWeek.indexOf(currentDay);
  while (dayNum < 0) {
    currentDay = prompt("Invalid day. Enter day of week:").toLowerCase();
    dayNum = daysOfWeek.indexOf(currentDay);
  }
  let daysLeft = 6-daysOfWeek.indexOf(currentDay);
  console.log(daysLeft == 0 ? "last day of the week " : daysLeft);    
}
  days();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this, my example uses a while loop to use the key of the day chosen as an iterator. Then you can shift the first value off the stack and return the remaining values in an array.

If this was not what you were looking for let me know and I can update or remove this answer.

```js
var daysOfWeek = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"];

function getDaysRemaining(arr) {
  let currentDay = prompt("Enter day of week:")
  daysOfWeek.includes(currentDay.toLowerCase()) ? currentDay = currentDay.toLowerCase() : currentDay = prompt("Invalid day. Enter day of week:").toLowerCase()
  let dayKey = daysOfWeek.indexOf(currentDay)
  let i = 1
  while (i <= dayKey) {
    arr.shift()
    i++
  }
  return arr
}

console.log(getDaysRemaining(daysOfWeek))
```